# Shutdown Dropwizard after starting it from maven for acceptance tests

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard, acceptance-testing, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm working on a multimodule maven project. We use dropwizard and in order to execute the acceptance tests we start the application using maven-antrun-plugin but the problem is that the appliction does not stop when the tests are finished then I have to kill the process from the task manager. I googled a lot but without result. Is there any way to do that from maven(for Jenkins)?

I tried with stop goal but it doesn't work:

```
<execution>
   <id>stop-container</id>
   <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
   <goals>
      <goal>stop</goal>
   </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: Why you don't write junit tests? --> http://dropwizard.io/manual/testing.html#integrated-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't find a maven solution, I added a task to drop wizard to make a shutdown then I make an http post to the task using implemented class in the acceptance module.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>stop-container</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```